# How to Setup DateTime.ascx(Nerdinner Editor Templates) in mvc page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I Add DateTime Datetime.ascx

\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime>" %>
     <%= Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}",Model)) %>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function () {
                 $('#EventDate').datetime({
                     userLang: 'en',
                     americanMode: true
                 });
             });
            </script>
```

And I Need to Use it in my DateFrom - To Texbox.

```
<%@ Register src="../Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.ascx" tagname="DateTime" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<p>
        Please enter your Date Range Below.
    </p>
           <p>
    Please enter your Date Range Below.
</p>
    <form method="post" action="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(Url.Action("List")) %>">
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="vertical">
            <tr>
                <th>Date From:</th>
                <td><%= Html.TextBox("datefrom") %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Date To:</th>
                <td><%= Html.TextBox("dateto")%></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Show My Orders" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

I got the Datetime.ascx from Nerdinner

Thanks in Regards

Comment: have you looked at using HTML Helper instead of a User Control see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: In addition to the correct answer by Linkgoron, is the javascript going to do what you intended?

Comment: I got the Datetime.ascx from Nerdinner

Comment: Don't forget that in addition you'll also need to include JQuery and JQuery.ui (for the date picker)  javascript files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the  `Html.EditorFor` instead of `Html.TextBox`

BTW, can you even use the <%@ register ..%> syntax in MVC? I've only ever used it in ASP.NET WebForms (although, I'm only using Razor now so my ASCX is kind of rusty)